# IGSON fromJSon method don´t works correct - why?

Tags: java, json

I have the following JSON Code:

```
{
    "tstamp": "2012-11-21 18:00",
    "id": 123,
    "publicationList": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "state": "Publication.IMMEDIATELY",
            "channel": "Channel.TIMETABLE",
            "startDate": "2001-12-17",
            "endDate": "2001-12-17"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to generate an Java object. Remember that publicationList is a Java.Util.List

```
MessageDto messageDto = gson.fromJson(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(
           "mapper/message.json")),
            MessageDto.class);
```

Gson Configuration:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").create();
```

I get the following error message:

```
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: The JsonDeserializer com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@3782da3d failed to deserialize json object [{"id":"1","state":"Publication.IMMEDIATELY","channel":"Channel.TIMETABLE","startDate":"2001-12-17","endDate":"2001-12-17"}]
```

I forgot an important Information! The "publicationList" works with an Interface and not with an correcht Java POJO. Now i think, that i need an deserialzer, which was written by myself.

Comment: Please post the code for `MessageDto`.

Comment: You need to correct your MessageDto class, share it to get the right help

Comment: You need to create two separate Value Object classes to parse your JSON. One containing the `tstamp,id,publicationList with the ArrayList of publicationList` and another containing the details of the publicationList values.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is an array, not an object.

Comment: ok, but how is it a correct object? What is my mistake? How can i make an object in JSON?

Comment: you should post MessageDto as well.  But your main mistake is your JSON does not match the class you are trying to read it into.  See http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Comment: His JSON is valid (it's not an array).

Comment: `[{"id":...` looks like an array to me.  it looks like the publicationList part of his object